# SMTP Server Stops on Windows 2008 - Why? And Can I Auto Start It?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-6, smtp

I have a Windows 2008 server and am running IIS 6 SMTP on it.  Occasionally email will stop working and when I log into the server I see that the SMTP Virtual Server has stopped.

What are some causes for this and is there a way I can auto correct the issue by having it start up again by itself or something similar?

Also, if there isn't a good way to keep it running without user intervention is there something else I can use for a SMTP server that is easy to setup?

Answer (score 3):

After you've corrected the problem you can set the Recovery options of the service (from the properties of the service) to restart the service if it stops.

Comment: The Display Name of the Service is: 
Simple Mail Transfer Protocol

Answer (score 2):

IIS SMTP can certainly be stable. You need to review the Event Logs on the server to look for errors around the time the SMTP service stops to determine why it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

The startup type for the service is by default set to "Manual". Which will cause the service to be stopped after a reboot.